# Laravel: Polymorphic Relationships (morphTo, morphMany) or Regular Relationships (hasOne, hasMany) with conditions?

Tags: php, laravel, database

Sample Case:

```
posts
    id - integer
    title - string
    body - text  

videos
    id - integer
    title - string
    url - string   

comments
    id - integer
    body - text
    commentable_id - integer
    commentable_type - string
```

Which one is better?

1. Polymorphic Relationships (morphTo, morphMany).

> ```
> public function comments(): MorphMany
> {
>     return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
> }
> ```

2. Regular Relationships (hasOne, hasMany)

> ```
> public function comments()
> {
>     return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'commentable_id', 'id')->where('commentable_type','=','App\Models\Post');
> }
> ```

Can someone please provide a detailed explanation? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already been through [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

Here are some basic differences:

> In Laravel, a "one-to-many" relationship represents the relationship between one record in a table and many records in another table.

> On the other hand, a "polymorphic one-to-many" relationship represents a relationship where a single record in a table can be associated with many records across multiple tables. This allows for more flexible relationships between tables.

> > Here are some key differences between the two types of relationships:

> > One-to-many relationships are straightforward and are used when you know that a record in one table is always associated with many records in another table. Polymorphic relationships, on the other hand, are more complex and are used when you need to associate a record with many records in multiple tables.

> > In a one-to-many relationship, the foreign key is stored in the "many" table. In a polymorphic relationship, there are two fields that are used to store the relationship: a foreign key that references the parent table and a field that stores the type of the related record.

> > One-to-many relationships are faster to query since there is only one table involved. Polymorphic relationships require more complex queries since multiple tables are involved.